# Unable to create OpenShift application using --from-code option

Tags: nginx, sinatra, openshift, paas, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to create an OpenShift application using the `--from-code` option to grab the application code from GitHub. I've created two different OpenShift QuickStarts -- with one, the `--from-code` option works, and with the other, it doesn't work.

So clearly I'm doing something wrong in the QuickStart that isn't working. But I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I either get `error 504` or `an error occurred`, neither of which tells me what the problem is, and there doesn't seem to be a `verbose` flag to get more details on the error.

```
Tests-Mac:~ testuser$ rhc app create sonr diy-0.1 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart --from-code https://github.com/citrusbyte/SONR.git
The cartridge 'http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart' will be downloaded and installed

Application Options
-------------------
Domain:      schof
Cartridges:  diy-0.1, http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart
Source Code: https://github.com/citrusbyte/SONR.git
Gear Size:   default
Scaling:     no

Creating application 'sonr' ... Server returned an unexpected error code: 504
Tests-Mac:~ testuser$ rhc app create sonr diy-0.1 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart --from-code https://github.com/citrusbyte/SONR.git
The cartridge 'http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart' will be downloaded and installed

Application Options
-------------------
Domain:      schof
Cartridges:  diy-0.1, http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart
Source Code: https://github.com/citrusbyte/SONR.git
Gear Size:   default
Scaling:     no

Creating application 'sonr' ... 
An error occurred while communicating with the server. This problem may only be temporary. Check that you have correctly specified your
OpenShift server 'https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domain/schof/applications'.
Tests-Mac:~ testuser$
```

That's creating an application with `--from-code` using this repo: https://github.com/citrusbyte/SONR . If I use this repo it works flawlessly: https://github.com/citrusbyte/openshift-sinatra-redis

The code itself seems to be good, as I can create an empty new application, merge the SONR code in, and it works flawlessly.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: I've worked around this issue by creating the app in two stages instead of doing it in one stage:

```
rhc app create APPNAME diy-0.1 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart
cd APPNAME
git remote add github -f https://github.com/citrusbyte/SONR.git
git merge github/master -s recursive -X theirs
git push origin master
```

I'd still love to know why doing it in one step was failing, though.

Answer (score 1):

@developercorey had the right idea.

I tried with a ridiculous timeout of 99999, and then got a different timeout error that I don't think I can change:

```
$ rhc app create APPNAME diy-0.1 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart --from-code https://github.com/citrusbyte/SONR.git --timeout 99999
...
Creating application 'APPNAME' ... 
The initial build for the application failed: Shell command '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 5328a9385973ca70150002af -c "exec /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c5,c974' /bin/sh -c \"gear postreceive --init >> /tmp/initial-build.log 2>&1\""' exceeded timeout of 229
```

The fix I mentioned in my earlier update is working perfectly, and that's what I recommend anyone with a similar problem try -- I'm creating the app as empty without the `--from-code` option, and then merging in the code I wanted to use in a separate step:

```
rhc app create APPNAME diy-0.1 http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart
cd APPNAME
git remote add github -f https://github.com/citrusbyte/SONR.git
git merge github/master -s recursive -X theirs
git push origin master
```

Comment: Looking at `--debug` output it seems timeout would be in milliseconds, if so 99999ms is merely 1.67min, perhaps less than the default (I'm seeing 5min timeouts with [my scaling app](https://github.com/cben/mathdown/issues/115); but I also tried `--timeout 9999999`  with no difference.  I'm not seeing "The initial build for the application failed" errors on create but I do get them on scaling up to a 2nd gear (with "timeout of 200").

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the application takes to long to clone/setup, and the creation is timing out.  Something you can try is to create the application without the --from-code, then clone it locally, and merge in your code from github, then do a git push.  This operation has a much longer timeout period, and will also let you see what, if any, errors that you get since the application won't disappear if it doesn't succeed, unlike an app create.

Comment: Thanks, @developercorey. I actually did that, as indicated in the update above. I'll take your advice on the timeout and try the operation with a much longer timeout.

Comment: App creations get 2 minutes i believe, so if you are doing a big build process, it might be worth having the build already in the repository and have it just copied to the correct place, or maybe have it pre-compiled and install it as a cartridge instead of a quickstart.